# MySQL - Stored procedure return null if called by CLI but result in workbench

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, command-line-interface, mysql-workbench

I'm writing a stored procedure on mysql, but I have no idea why when called from the workbench it gives correct answer but when called by either PHP API or CLI it gives NULLs.

In my case the procedure is this:

```
use dummydb
delimiter GO
create procedure myproc (startdate datetime, enddate datetime)
begin
select @startdate as beg, @enddate as fin;
end
GO
delimiter ;
```

when I call it from workbench `call myproc ("2018-03-01", "2020-11-11");` it returns:

```
beg         fin
2018-03-01  2020-11-11
```

but when I call it from CLI:

```
mysql> use dummydb
Database changed
mysql> call myproc('2018-03-01','2020-03-01');
+------+------+
| beg  | fin  |
+------+------+
| NULL | NULL |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

and when I call it from php it returns 2014

```
// [....]
$conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "theuser", "thepassword", "dummydb");

$sql = "CALL myproc('2018-03-01', '2020-11-11')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

var_dump($result->fetch_assoc());
```

returns this:

```
array(2) {
  'beg' =>
  NULL
  'fin' =>
  NULL
}
```

How could I make it pass correct values?

Comment: Don't use `@` for the variables. These are 2 different types of variables - with and without `@`

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure has input parameters `startdate` and `enddate`. Then in your procedure you are referring to [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) `@startdate` and `@enddate`. These two are two separate thing.

The user-defined variables are session specific, i.e. they maintain their value throughout the session. When you call your procedure, it shows the values from the session, not the input parameter values. In your workbench session these variables have values, but in your CLI not.

To use the input variables in procedures use the same variables (and preferably use a prefix so you do not eventually mix them with column names):

```
create procedure myproc (in_startdate datetime, in_enddate datetime)
begin
select in_startdate as beg, in_enddate as fin;
end
```

Comment: The thing I can't explain myself is why the same procedure with user-defined-like vars called in workbench works but does not in CLI

Comment: In your workspace session the variables are defined. In CLI not. The result will be the same if you just run: `select @startdate, @enddate`. The variables have nothing to do with the procedure.